# XPath for text within an XML element?

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I new to web services response handling techniques. I have the soap response below,
from which I want to get the UID value.

```
<Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle = "">
   <Body xmlns:m = ""> 
     <CreateUser>
     <m:status>SUCCESS</m:status>
     <m:code>1</m:code>
     <m:uid>1234t</m:uid>
   </CreateUser>
   </Body> 
</Envelope>
```

I tried this xpath traversal:

```
/Envelope/Body/CreateUser/m:uid
```

which yields:

```
<m:uid>1234t</m:uid>
```

I need just `1234t`.

Comment: Isn't what you get actually what you want? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @AlexeyR.: It's the difference between selecting an element versus getting the string value of that element (or its child text node).  [See below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46612492/290085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
/Envelope/Body/CreateUser/m:uid
```

yields

```
<m:uid>1234t</m:uid>
```

then

```
string(/Envelope/Body/CreateUser/m:uid)
```

and

```
/Envelope/Body/CreateUser/m:uid/text()
```

will yield

```
1234t
```

as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  tried as suggested, it return blank value.

Comment: Then either `/Envelope/Body/CreateUser/m:uid` didn't return `<m:uid>1234t</m:uid>` as you say it did, or you're calling your XPath library improperly (and we can't comment on that since you've not shown it).